# Can't set custom font on my UILabels

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uilabel, uifont

I am trying to set a custom font on my `UILabels`

- Font name:  `Lucida Sans Unicode.ttf`
- Font postscript: `LucidaSans-Typewriter`

Now I have added the font to my Plist with the name `Lucida-Sans-Unicode.ttf`. I've added the '-' because I read somewhere that the spaces maybe can cause the problem. I also changed the name of the font to the name with the '-' in it.

Finally on my Label I call the font like this.

```
[UIFont fontWithName:@"LucidaSans-Typewriter" size:12.0f]
```

But still the font has not been set correctly. Can someone help me ?

Kind regards

Comment: Ok. Here we're talking about two different families (`Lucida Sans Unicode` & `Lucida Sans Typewriter`)... so including the one in the bundle and trying to use the other wouldn't work for sure...

Comment: Install the ttf file on your machine and check out the name that appears on your system. The same name should be given in fontWithName: method. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First check it out that you give outlet to that `UILabel` correctly and then use bellow code..

```
UIFont *myFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-BoldOblique" size:20];
[yourLable setFont:myFont];
```

here if you used `LucidaSans` font then first check that this font available in your system or not then try with bellow code..

```
UIFont *myFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"LucidaSans-Typewriter" size:12.0f];
[yourLable setFont:myFont];
```

Answer (score 5):

Here are the steps transcribed:

1) Add your custom font files into your project using Xcode as a resource 
   2) Add a key to your Info.plist file called `Fonts provided by application`. 
   3)  Make this key an array 
   4) For each font you have, enter the full name of your font file (including the extension) as items to the `Fonts provided by application` array
   5) Save Info.plist
    Now in your application you can simply call

```
 [myLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Swis721 Lt BT" size:[lbl minimumFontSize]]]; //use font name not file name.
```

no need to added the '-' because it doesn't meter.